# Executing Selenium webdriver via PHP exec()

Tags: php, python, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I have built a python script, which uses Selenium and Firefox to load some websites and process their content. Since I want to use the output of that script in PHP, I am using PHP's exec() function.

My python test script looks like this:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
import sys

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

print("Driver started")

driver.quit()
display.stop()
```

When running it from the command line, I get the expected "Driver started" output.

However, when running it inside a PHP script like this:

```
exec("python test.py 2>&1", $output);
```

The python script produces following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in 
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 152, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 188, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

I should also mention that on the command line I tried running the script both as root and as another user and both worked. The webserver is executing it using the "nginx" user, which i can't su into on the command line cause it's occupied by the webserver. But I assume that, just like with my test user, the nginx user should also have all necessary permissons to run the script.

Firefox version: Mozilla Firefox 52.1.0

Selenium version: 3.4.3

Geckodriver version: 0.16.1

**Update**
Tried to run executables such as Firefox from php, but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Could finally fix the problem. It seems that somehow the firefox binary wasn't found automatically while running the script via PHP exec(). So the fix for the problem was to do the following:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

print("Driver started")

driver.quit()
display.stop()
```